# Rails webpacker.yml, extract_css option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

According to rails/webpacker documentation, extract_css is default to true in production environment and false in development. From what I observed:

- With extract_css true, webpacker will emit a css file from each stylesheet_pack_tag in application.html.erb.
- And, with extract_css false, stylesheet_pack_tag return nil & stylesheet that gets imported in js files will get extracted and bundle into blobs and send to browser. Hence, link tags to blob url exist.

So, I assume that using extract_css true yield the same result as using inline styles in header since styles get downloaded to browser with the website document file. If what I understand is true then setting extract_css to true on production should be ok.

Is what I understand about extract_css option correct?

Comment: I'm using extract_css: false in production & no problem so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mostly correct, you can read more about `extract_css` in [css.md](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/css.md#link-styles-from-your-rails-views) or v4-[upgrade.md](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/v4-upgrade.md#upgrading-projects-with-custom-webpack-setups-that-use-only-the-view-helpers)

With `extract_css: true`, webpacker will emit a **single** css **`<link rel="stylesheet"...`** from each stylesheet_pack_tag.

With `extract_css: false`, stylesheet_pack_tag return nil & stylesheet that gets imported in js files will get extracted and bundle into blobs and **injected into  as an inline** .

In the end **`extract_css: false`** is the one that yields the same result as using inline styles.

Comment: so, true or false, which is better?

Comment: @new2cpp with true, CSS will be extracted out of the JavaScript, and be available in the head of your page so the consequence is that you web browser will parallelize the downloading of the CSS and JS. This mode is great for production since you'll have static files. In development mode, you'd rather prefer to get all from webpack since when you change a file, you want to get the update without re-compiling everything, so false will be best in that case. Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have anything to add other than "extract_css" in webpacker.yml has been a source of confusion for me as well. When it is "extract_css: false" in development and production, a stylesheet IS included in the document head (shouldn't this be "extract_css: true"?). And when I use "extract_css: true", styles are not included in the document.